# How to create a live connection between MS Access and SQL Server?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The data I am using is stored in a SQL database and an Access database. Regular data entry needs to be made in the Access database, however, I would like to write my queries in SQL Management Studio.   I have connected the two databases using an ODBC connection and I can now view the tables in Management studio but the connection is not live, so any updates in Access are not reflected in the tables in Management Studio.

Comment: You should link to the SQL tables and make your updates directly in there from your access front end. Ideally all your tables would reside in SQL, except any "local user"  related data.

Comment: Thank you but I want to update the Access tables, not the SQL tables. The linked Access tables made through the OCDB connection do not refresh on the SQL side.

Comment: I don't think you can link to an access table from SQL with a "live" connection. You would normally store all your data in SQL and then query / update it from Access as a front end.

Comment: SQL Server SQL syntax is different from Access, so your request makes little sense IMHO.

Comment: If you link to the tables on SQL server from Access, then you don't have local access tables. Any update made in the Access front end via any form or even Access SQL will be thus instant reflected on SQL server because there is only one copy of the data. There not a built in nor practical means that when you update a local access table, then updates by magic appear on the sql server side. You could attempt to build some type of "sync" systems, but that is a lot of work, and you really don't have a means that after one record is edited in Access that it will somehow update sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a linked table from Access to SQL Server (INSERT INTO).  You can use SQL or VBA to export all data from Access to SQL Server.

Here is one idea.

```
Sub modExportToPG()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 'We only want to export physical user defined visible and hidden tables
       Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Name " &  _
        " FROM MSysObjects " & _
        "   WHERE Type=1 AND Flags < 9 ORDER BY Name;")

    Do Until rs.EOF
        'export the tables but export as lower case table names
        DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database" _
         , "ODBC;DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};DATABASE=mydb;SERVER=myserver;PORT=5432;UID=myuser;PWD=mypwd" _ 
         , acTable, rs("Name"), LCase(rs("Name"))
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
End Sub
```

Also, see this for more ideas.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1480/configure-microsoft-access-linked-tables-with-a-sql-server-database/

Answer (score 0):

Came upon this s little late but I am in the midst of working through a project where we update SQL side tables at the same time that we update local and shared (server side) Access tables.  It is a fairly extensive application, but the SQL updates are relatively easy and there are options.  The application integrates with a Point of Sale back office server and we are sensitive to the data that gets updated instantly, so those items get tucked into batches that require approval before they get "posted" to SQL.  Those items that are not sensitive we post immediately using the afterupdate property for each field on the main form using the following code (sample only):

Private Sub Field.AfterUpdate

```
Dim Var1 as string
Dim Var2 as string
Dim Var3 as string

'Capture Before and after values for the field (as well as using the_
 newvalue   to post to SQL, we store these separately as audit records_
 so we capture both old and new).

    Var1 = Me.Field.OldValue
    Var2 = Me.Field.NewValue
    Var3 = Me.PID.Text

'Execute the SQL update
DoCmd.DbExecute "Update dbo.SQLTABLE SET SQLField = '" & Var2 & "'_
WHERE SQLTABLE.PID = '" & Var3 & "'
```

End Sub

Note:  PID is a record id attached to every record in the access form that matches a corresponding record in a SQL Table (primary key).

It is a lot of work if you have a number of fields to post but it's as good as it gets using linked tables in my experience.  This is a simple example and ours are far more extensive, but it does the trick.